# How to validate DNSSEC in PHP?

Tags: php

I've been trying to figure out a way to validate DNS records in PHP (`oa1`) but have come up short.

I can validate a whole domain with this library, but not the individual records: https://github.com/metaregistrar/php-dnssec-validator

In addition, that library only allows for a very small set of TLDs to be validated.

Is there another library out there that can handle this for me, or perhaps something else I should look into?

I've also found this: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9031-PHP-Validate-DNSSEC-keys-and-calculate-the-DS-record.html

But I have no idea how to get the keys to use in their validating function.

Help please!

***UPDATE***

So, I ended up using this...

```
exec('host -t RRSIG ' . $domain, $output);
```

Returns the RRSIG, or lack thereof, with minimal hassle.

Comment: This function won't work?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php.

Comment: Oh, maybe! I didn't find this function at all. Lemme look and see.

Comment: Opps, that function returns a bool, but this one might be more useful:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php

Comment: Haha, I was just writing that. I'm using that one already to read TXT records and it works great. However, I can't seem to find out what the DNSSEC records will be stored under now. Maybe that's the 'IN' type?

Comment: They should be under DNSKEY, RRSIG, types I think.  At least that is what is returned to dig: https://docs.menandmice.com/display/MM/How+to+test+DNSSEC+validation

Comment: Ok, not totally sure, but it *seems* like dns_get_record doesn't return RRSIG. Sigh. At least none of the domains that *should* have it are returning that record.

Comment: Hmm, I checked http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types and it looks like there are a lot of dnssec related records, unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, the RRSIG ones are the ones that I need to check I believe, but I'm still pretty sure that dns_get_record doesn't get those for some reason. Thanks though!

Comment: So I ended up using an exec() with the 'host' command. Works like a charm :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1) Going to the shell, from PHP, just to do a DNS query is really a bad idea, both for security and performance reasons. But more important even there, 2) fetching RRSIG records does not validate anything related to DNSSEC, especially since you do not specify which nameserver you are using.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP engine has a fixed set of DNS record types it supports, all defined by the [`type`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php) parameter to `dns_get_record`.  You can double check this list by looking in the [engine code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/dns.c#L289-L304) that implements DNS queries.

Unfortunately, none of the DNSSEC records are in that pre-defined list.  So, you need to rely on a library or an external tool.

I'd use [`Net_DNS2`](https://netdns2.com/), as it supports many [DNSSEC RR](https://netdns2.com/documentation/resource-records-supported/).  Example:

```
$google = new \Net_DNS2_Resolver(['nameservers' => ['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4']]);
$google->dnssec = true;
try {
    $result = $google->query('kyhwana.org', 'SSHFP');
} catch(\Net_DNS2_Exception $ex) {
    die($ex->getMessage());
}

foreach ($result->answer as $answer) {
    if ($answer instanceof \Net_DNS2_RR_SSHFP) {
        printf(
            '%s %d %s %s %d %d %s' . PHP_EOL,
            $answer->name,
            $answer->ttl,
            $answer->class,
            $answer->type,
            $answer->algorithm,
            $answer->fp_type,
            $answer->fingerprint
        );
    } else if ($answer instanceof \Net_DNS2_RR_RRSIG) {
        printf('Signed by %s: %s' . PHP_EOL, $answer->signname, $answer->signature);
    }
}
```

*Aside: if your domain uses ECDSA algorithm or the SHA-256 fingerprint (like the example above), then you need the latest Net_DNS2 code which fixes [Issue #39](https://github.com/mikepultz/netdns2/issues/39).*

Comment: You forgot the most important line - `use pear\net_dns2;` - took forever to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

I haven't implemented the code yet but it looks to me like using php to verify the signatures themselves is a mistake. Use a local recursive resolver like unbound on the local server that enforces DNSSEC.

Then in php with the PEAR module Net_DNS2 look for an RRSIG record for the domain of interest. The result should tell you the zone responsible for that record.

Look for a DNSKEY record in that zone. If present, then look for a DS record.

The DS record will come from the parent zone (e.g. .email for deviant.email) and if present indicates DNSSEC is present for the zone.

If DNSSEC is present for the zone, then all the results for the zone are valid if your local recursive nameserver enforces DNSSEC.

I believe with Net_DNS2 that using

```
r = new Net_DNS2_Resolver(array('nameservers' => array('127.0.0,1')));
r->dnssec = true;
```

will also result in Net_DNS2 also validating the results if DNSSEC is active - which is indicated by the DS record that comes from the parent zone. But using a recursive resolver (preferably on the webserver) that enforces DNSSEC is probably safest.

Make sure the recursive resolver isn't listening on public interfaces so it doesn't get used in reflective amplification attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same goal (validate DNSSEC in PHP), i ended up with:

```
exec("drill -k root.keys -TDQ $domain SOA | grep -v '^;;'", $output);
```

This is doing a **complete** topdown DNSSEC validation.

You need root keys you can retrieve with:

```
unbound-anchor # NB: on FreeBSD, use local-unbound-anchor for "base" version
```

Or "manually":

```
dig . dnskey > root.keys
```

To confirm that the record is fully DNSSEC validated, check the last line of exec output:

- [S] self sig OK *This is not satisfying, probably zone key has not been populated in parent zone*
- [B] bogus
- [T] trusted *This means that everything is OK!*